# Ensuring DatePicker is available in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker

I have a question to which I couldn't really find an answer for with a Google Search. I'm working on a VBA assignment, one of the sections requires the user to enter a start and end date which will be used to filter through a set of data. I have been using the DatePicker package and it has been working fine. I then emailed my assignment (to myself) to work on later on, and noticed that the DatePickers don't show up on the forms. When I open my assignment, an error message pops up saying "Could not load some objects because they are not available on this machine". Now, the Date Pickers are already installed on the computer I am using, but they have to be added through the menus in excel.

Anyway, I was just wondering if there is anyway I can ensure that the date pickers will be available with the Excel file that I eventually submit. Otherwise, I will have to input the dates through another mechanism (which is fine, but the Date Pickers provide a nicer visual than the drop down lists of Day, Month, Year.

I hope this question is clear and thank you for any help

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no included DatePicker (or similar). The only way to make it available from all locations would be some kind of self-pulling makro using a repository, but that's way over the top for what you will need. I suggest falling back to a TextBox, and maybe adding some autocomplete-gimmicks for easier entry.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not have a date picker calendar control out of the box that seamlessly works in all versions. There are some ActiveX controls that can be used in earlier versions, but they won't work with later versions.

Ron de Bruin has written a VBA data picker tool that works in all Excel versions and has a collection of info about the calendar control on his page here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s8/win003.htm